# CakePHP routing help. Default to another route

Tags: url, cakephp, routes

I'm trying to implement a custom route to catch this url

www.site.com/username

```
Router::connect ('/:username/*', 
array ('controller'=>'users', 'action'=>'view'),
array ('pass'=> array ('username')  
));
```

but if a user is not found, apply my default project routes and not getting an error.

I have a bunch of controllers and actions, and If I setup the previous route, I'm afraid they all will stop working??

I mean, how can i have working all the default controllers like:

```
www.site.com/admin/
www.site.com/users/edit/15
www.site.com/pages/help
```

etc., while being able to have a custom route like

```
www.site.com/:username
```

Any help or advise will be very much appreciated

Comment: I'm trying to avoid to have a url like twitter used to ave in the form www.site.com/#/username

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom route class to do the parser.

Mark has a post to explain it:
http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp

And you also can read the documentation here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes